# KOTLIN / JAVA: String doesn't get replaced in a loop

Tags: java, kotlin

```
val string = "8% of 25 is the same as <img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"limit\">There are no heroes in a punk rock band <img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"limit\">"

val arraySearchInTheStringVariableAbove = arrayOf(
    "<img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"limit\">", 
    "<img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"limit\">"
)

val arrayReplacementInTheStringVariableAbove = arrayOf(
    "<img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"another-limit\" data-id=\"1\">", 
    "<img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"another-limit\" data-id=\"2\">"
)

arraySearchInTheStringVariableAbove.forEachIndexed { index, it ->
    string.replace(it, arrayReplacementInTheStringVariableAbove[index])
}

println(string)
```

the string doesn't get replaced. still shows:

`8% of 25 is the same as <img src="/someimage.png" class="limit">There are no heroes in a punk rock band <img src="/someimage.png" class="limit">`

where it should have been

`8% of 25 is the same as <img src="/someimage.png" class="another-limit" data-id="1">There are no heroes in a punk rock band <img src="/someimage.png" class="another-limit" data-id="2">`

notice the `<img>` tag gets replaced sequentially

Comment: `String` is immutable, so `replace` doesn't modify the object its called on, but returns a new modified one instead. You ignore that return value, effectively making the whole method call pointless.

Comment: To make this work you'd need to put the new string created by `replace` into the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` is immutable, every time you transform it, it creates new `String` in `StringPool`, you can assign it back to same `string` as `var`

```
var string = "8% of 25 is the same as <img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"limit\">There are no heroes in a punk rock band <img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"limit\">"

val arraySearchInTheStringVariableAbove = arrayOf(
    "<img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"limit\">", 
    "<img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"limit\">"
)

val arrayReplacementInTheStringVariableAbove = arrayOf(
    "<img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"another-limit\" data-id=\"1\">", 
    "<img src=\"/someimage.png\" class=\"another-limit\" data-id=\"2\">"
)

arraySearchInTheStringVariableAbove.forEachIndexed { index, it ->
    string = string.replace(it, arrayReplacementInTheStringVariableAbove[index])
}

println(string)
```

Comment: tried with `listOf`. I notice weird behavior when the data-id value is always 1. this the code: https://pastebin.com/jDm7U6ic .

Comment: `8% of 25 is the same as <img src="/someimage.png" class="another-limit" data-id="1">There are no heroes in a punk rock band <img src="/someimage.png" class="another-limit" data-id="1">` . notice the data-id value

Comment: use replaceFirst instead, because `replace` replaces all occurences

Answer (score 4):

Java and Kotlin strings are immutable and not editable in place. `replace()` returns a new string that you're throwing away.

One way to fix that is change the `val string` to a `var string` and assign the returned string back to it.